# isempty and variables in Range

Tags: excel, vba

This code always returns cells is not empty.  Why is this?  Is my range incorrect?  This code is in a command button on another sheet.  I also intend to make the row numbers execute in a for loop but need to get this code working properly before proceeding.  Please note I have the column address, number and letter.

Any help appreciated- thanks
Jerry

```
columnletterstart = "A"
columnletterend = "D"

Let therange = columnletterstart & "20" & ":" & columnletterend & "20"
Cells(6, 6) = therange
If IsEmpty(Worksheets("Vacation Schedule").Range(therange)) = False Then
    'Cell A2 is not blank
    MsgBox "Cell is not empty"
Else
    'Cell A2 is blank
    MsgBox "Cell is empty"
End If
```

Comment: Are there formulas in range `A20:D20`?

Comment: I think you have to loop through each cell. Alternatively, depending on what you're trying to do you could use worksheet functions COUNTBLANK or COUNTA.

Comment: ***UNCLEAR***........Are you trying to test if ALL the cells in the range are empty or are you trying to see if ANY of the cells in the range are empty??

Comment: Just verified that there are no formulas in A20:D20.  I am trying to copy a row of data in between 2 columns onto another sheet.  I am looking for all cells empty in the range

Answer (score 2):

You're passing `IsEmpty` a multi-celled range (A20:D20), which it interprets as a 2D Variant array, which *isn't empty* because it's an initialized array of empty variants. `IsEmpty` would work with a single-celled range that doesn't contain a formula.

Example for IsEmpty and a single cell:

```
If IsEmpty(Worksheets("Example").Cells(1, 1).Value2) Then ...
```

As mentioned by @SJR, to check for the emptiness of a range covering multiple cells, you want to look at `COUNTA`:

```
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Vacation Schedule").Range(therange)) > 0 Then
```

**Edit**

A recurring issue is that you sometimes want to consider cells containing a zero-length string as being empty; `Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA` counts such cells, whether they contain constants (e.g. `'`) or formulas resulting in `""`.

The following function optionally skips zero-length strings when considering the emptiness of a range:

```
Public Function IsRangeEmpty(ByVal prngTest As Excel.Range, pbZeroLengthStringIsEmpty As Boolean) As Boolean
    IsRangeEmpty = prngTest.Find("*", LookIn:=IIf(pbZeroLengthStringIsEmpty, xlValues, xlFormulas), LookAt:=xlPart, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, MatchByte:=False, SearchFormat:=False) Is Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I had kind of the same problem this week.

Because `IsEmpty`and `CountA` didn't return the correct result I ended up writing my own method:

```
Function CheckRange(passedRange As range) As Boolean

Dim cell As range
Dim rangeCounter As Integer

rangeCounter = 0

For Each cell In passedRange

    If cell.Value <> "" Then
        rangeCounter = rangeCounter + 1
        Exit For
    End If

Next cell

If rangeCounter = 0 Then
    CheckRange = True
Else
    CheckRange = False
End If

End Function
```

Call it like this:

```
Dim columnletterstart As String
Dim columnletterend As String
Dim concatenateString As String

Dim testRange As range

columnletterstart = "A"
columnletterend = "D"
concatenateString = columnletterstart & "20" & ":" & columnletterend & "20"

Set testRange = range(concatenateString)

If CheckRange(testRange) Then
    MsgBox "empty"
Else
    MsgBox "not empty"
End If
```

Comment: You should exit the loop as soon as you hit a value; imagine if the range was huge and the first cell was not "empty" - the code would continue scanning the whole range for nothing. See the IsRangeEmpty function in my answer for an alternative.

Comment: Replace the `CheckRange = False` you've just added by `Exit For`.

Comment: I replaced it; an u explain why it is better to exit the loop, instead of just exit the function?

Comment: Setting `CheckRange = False` within the loop won't exit the function. You can check that by putting this code line back and setting a breakpoint on it, then calling the function.

Comment: I'm not able to test it right now but that makes sense. So the return value just sets the function and doesn't exit it immediately.